# Import Error : libopencv_core.so.3.0:cannot open shared file

Tags: opencv, import

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I installed the opencv 3.0-beta version initially. Due to some reasons I switched back to an older version, 2.4.9, after uninstalling the older version using commands:

```
$> sudo make uninstall
$> sudo find / -name "*opencv*" -exec rm -i {} \;
```

and I removed opencv 3.0.

But now when I use opencv 2.4.9 and `import cv2` in Python, it shows

> Import Error :libopencv_core.so.3.0:cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Does it mean that uninstallation was incomplete. Or is there any way to solve this error and `import cv2` for opencv 2.4.9?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I fixed this by removing a cv2 file located in `"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages"` for the python2.7 version and removed another cv2 file in `"/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages"` for python 3.4 I forgot what the exact names of the files are but you should see it.

Answer (score 1):

After compile and install opencv 4.1.1 on my raspberry pi 4 (clean install) I got a similar message when I tried to import cv2 :

```
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Jul 25 2020, 13:03:44)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: libopencv_reg.so.3.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>>>
```

I tried [this solution](https://github.com/cggos/dip_cvqt/issues/1) but it didn't work, so I did it in a "dirty" way:

I ran the command

```
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ldconfig -v
```

I got a bunch of lines. The important ones:

```
...
/usr/local/lib:
    ....
    libopencv_reg.so.4.1 -> libopencv_reg.so.4.1.1
...
```

Then I created a symbolic link:

```
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd /usr/local/lib
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:/usr/local/lib $ sudo ln -s libopencv_reg.so.4.1.1 libopencv_reg.so.3.3
```

Finally, It worked!

```
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Jul 25 2020, 13:03:44)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'4.1.1'
>>>
```

After rebooting my raspberry pi and import cv2 again, new .so files were "missing" so I repeated the last step for all the other libopencv_*.so.4.1.1 files in '/usr/local/lib'

```
sudo ln -s libopencv_<<other_lib>>.so.4.1.1 libopencv_<<other_lib>>.so.3.3
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran find/remove for all of the following before I was able to reinstall successfully (I think lines 2 and 4 are the most important though):

```
sudo find / -name "*opencv*" -exec rm -i {} \;
sudo find / -name "*opencv*" -exec rm -r {} \;
sudo find / -name "*OpenCV*" -exec rm -i {} \;
sudo find / -name "*OpenCV*" -exec rm -r {} \;
sudo find / -name "*cv2*" -exec rm -i {} \;
sudo find / -name "*cv2*" -exec rm -r {} \;
```

I am using the script from this page for installation: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV.